# Navbar doesn't scroll to show links on smaller devices when using nicescroll plug-in

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the nice scroll plug-in and on smaller devices the the navbar doesn't show all links and there is no scroll bar either to view all links. I tried adding `.navbar-collapse` on my configuration for the nice scroll plug-in as shown below. It doesn't work.

```
$("html, .navbar-collapse, .modal").niceScroll({
    cursorcolor: '#F05F40',
    cursoropacitymin: '0',
    cursoropacitymax: '1',
    cursorwidth: '6px',
    zindex: 10000,
    scrollspeed: 200,
    mousescrollstep: 80,
    horizrailenabled: false,
});
```

I also tried adding the following properties to my CSS but didn't win.

```
.navbar-default {
  max-height: 51px; 
}

.navbar-collapse {
  max-height: none; 
}

@media (max-width: 768px){
  .navbar-default {
    max-height: none;
  }
}
```

How can I add a scrollbar for the navigation bar on small devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS use `"height"` property not `"max-height"`. The plugin will work.

Example code at **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/ZpYvzy)**

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you. It does help. I can now scroll through the navbar however I see both the default scroll bar and the nice scroll one. How can I get rid of the default one?

Comment: Ignore that first comment. I saw what was causing the problem. Thanks a lot.